# Information Exchange between two threads by calling a shared DLL

Tags: c, multithreading, dll, synchronization

Can you create a "conversation" (or-Information Exchange) between 2 threads, if those two threads are calling a shared DLL library? And, if this conversation is possible, What are the requirements or restrictions for it to actually take place between the threads?

This question was given to us by our professor. I can only assume, by the question's context, that my professor is referring to synchronization required between the two threads for the conversation to succeed, or restricting the DLL linking type (Implicit or Explicit).

Then again, assumptions or not, I am rather at a loss here :)

P.s. -  In this case, we are programming in C.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: I can't believe that this is your actual question. Have you somehow mangled the words somewhere? What were the exact words. If your professor wrote the above, then I would fail the professor!

Comment: Hey Dave, No words were mangled, that was the question... as is.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your professor is testing your understanding of what space DLLs are loaded into, and how this relates to threads.

Without doing your homework for you, I encourage you to consider what happens if two threads each call LoadLibrary() on a particular DLL.  Is the DLL loaded into the process twice?

Given the result of the above, what implications does this have regarding the two threads making calls into that DLL?

Comment: Hey Jeff, I think I understand where you're heading. If the linking is implicit, then memory allocated for the function called by the threads should be unique. If the linking is Explicit then two different functions (yet identical) will be created, and by so no allowing the "conversation" to occur. I hope i got it right....Thanks again :)

Comment: I think you still need to answer my original question, plus another:

1)  "consider what happens if two threads each call LoadLibrary() on a particular DLL. Is the DLL loaded into the process twice?"

2)  Do implicit and explicit DLL linking actually have any effect on where the DLL is placed in memory, or how it is initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about using Boost.Interprocess, because C++ has many implicit allocations. In general you need a system-wide mutex in order to synchronize access to that portion of memory.

Comment: If the threads are in the same process then the mutex would not need to by system wide.

Answer (score 0):

I think that give each thread calls for LoadLibrary() the system will allocate different memory segment for each DLL thus each thread will not have a mutual resource to work with thus they will be unable to exchange any information.

but...
Say we will link explicitly to the DLL using `#Pragam Comment(lib, "myDLL.lib")`
I think that in this way you'll be able to share resources between threads because the DLL is fully loaded at the program startup.

Jeff? .. is this right ?...